# Want to find status of sudo su - in multiple servers

Tags: bash, ssh, expect, su, sudoers

I have a bash script, `hostlist` file and an expect script:
Below is the bash script to take inputs from `hostlist` file and keep looping ssh for multiple servers.

```
for x in $(cat hostlist); do
./sudoscript.exp  $x
done
```

Below is the expect cum bash script I want to tun and collect outputs of `sudo su -` command. I just need to get outputs as '0 or non zero values in a file for successful run/execution of `'sudo su - '`. I just need to simulate the execution and check if the command runs successfully or not with out actually changing user to admin by doing `sudo su -`.

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh [lindex $argv 0]
expect "$"
send "sudo su -\r" exit ; echo $server:$? >> output
```

Can someone please suggest to complete the script above.

Comment: You can just pass a command to be executed remotely as the last argument to `ssh`. Also, that's not an `expect` script. It's a likely invalid `bash` script with a comment on the second line.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do?

Maybe you're trying to see if it is possible to become root without a password?  If that's the case, try:

```
for x in $(cat hostlist); do
  echo $x
  ssh $x sudo -l |egrep -w 'NOPASSWD:.*(ALL|/su)'
  echo
done
```

`sudo -l` will list what you can run.  It requires your password unless you have one or more commands that do not require your password (`ssh` won't run interactively when called with a command and without the `-t` flag. This is intentional since we don't want that).

The `egrep` command limits the results to just what can be done without a password as well as either ALL commands or else `su` itself.  (Note, this won't find `su` if it's in an [alias](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers#Aliases).)